# How To delete a tcl Interpreter?

Tags: c++, tcl

I am having an application in c++ and I am using tcl interpreter for this.I have created a tcl interpreter for my application using

```
Tcl_Interp *_tclInterp = Tcl_CreateInterp();
```

And I have intialized this interpreter in a function. I want to delete/unset the interpreter at last inside the same function in which I have intialized it. So that when I do a

```
Get("tcl");
```

call I donot get the same interpreter.

So my question is how to delete/unset the tcl interpreter.

Comment: Well one thing's for sure, and that is that you should call `delete _tclInterp;` somewhere.

Comment: @chris Probably not. The library had a special function to create it, so the library probably has a function to delete it.

Comment: Tcl_DeleteInterp(_tclInterp);

Comment: @EthanSteinberg, good point. I completely missed the fact that `new` wasn't used.

Comment: I agree with @Ethan as we are not using new operator to create the interpreter, it is done internally by library, So I would expect a delete method for deleting the interpreter.

Comment: Doesn't the Tcl interpreter library have documentation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must *not* use the C++ `delete` operator on a Tcl interpreter.
Tcl's implementation is in C (for various reasons that don't matter to this question) so you *must* use C idioms when interacting with it. In particular, `Tcl_CreateInterp` is paired with `Tcl_DeleteInterp`; they're even documented on the [same manual page](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclLib/CrtInterp.htm). (Tcl doesn't guarantee to free the memory instantly when you delete the interpreter with that function, as it waits until there are no more uses of it on the stack, but if you're deleting it at a sane point then you'll be fine. Internally, `Tcl_DeleteInterp` eventually ends up calling `free()` on the interpreter structure, which is correct because the interpreter was allocated via `malloc()`.) If you want RAII-style memory management, you'll have to wrap it in a small class (a Boost `scoped_ptr` is almost perfect, except that you need a different destructor).

The other thing to watch out for from C++ is that Tcl interpreters are *strictly* thread bound; the Tcl library makes extensive use of thread-local data internally to reduce the number of global locks to a bare minimum (in particular, Tcl doesn't have any of the weird global lock problems of the C implementation of Python). An interpreter can only ever be accessed or deleted from the same thread that created it.

Answer (score 0):

As [actual](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36174/actual) rightly points out, the correct function to call is `Tcl_DeleteInterp`, but there's more to it than that ([`man 3tcl Tcl_DeleteInterp`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclLib/CrtInterp.htm)):

> Tcl_DeleteInterp marks an interpreter as deleted; the interpreter will eventually be deleted when all calls to Tcl_Preserve for it have been matched by calls to Tcl_Release.

So if you're not doing any reference counting on your interpreter (`Tcl_Preserve`/`Tcl_Release`), then `Tcl_DeleteInterp` will delete your interpreter.

Comment: You don't normally need to do reference counting on an interpreter yourself; that's usually handled quite adequately inside Tcl's implementation. (Basically, the reference count is bumped up while a script is actively being executed.)